# Access Rest API - JHipster

Tags: jhipster

JHipster comes with Spring Actuator as default. According to [the document](http://jhipster.github.io/development.html), I shall be able to view application Rest APIs with a url something like localhost/api. I, however, get a "Access Denied" due to "Unauthorized (Unauthorized)" when I try to access it even I have logged in as the administrator. In the class SecurityConfiguration, I change the following method

```
   @Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/scripts/**/*.{js,html}")
        .antMatchers("/bower_components/**")
        .antMatchers("/i18n/**")
        .antMatchers("/assets/**")
        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html")
        .antMatchers("/api/**")   <-- new added
        .antMatchers("/api/register")
        .antMatchers("/api/activate")
        .antMatchers("/api/account/reset_password/init")
        .antMatchers("/api/account/reset_password/finish")
        .antMatchers("/test/**");
}
```

This change only yields an exception.

How can I access my application Rest APIs then?

Comment: have you ever tried looking at code?

Answer (score 0):

Login into application -> `Administration` -> `API`

It is better to watch [jHipster tutorial](http://jhipster.github.io/video_tutorial.html).

Comment: I forgot the one. I used Token authorization and couldn't access the api. So, I tried to use the feature Spring Boot provides.

Answer (score 0):

I use jhipster also, to be able to send requests with postMan, i change the method PublicApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter in the class SecurityConfigurationSaml.java. I just have to add a regexMatcher to the link where i'm doing my request.
I think that the security of links is coded on this class.